# Помогите разобраться с куками для sortable блоков

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript

Всем привет, не могу заставить нормально работать куки для боксов, которые сортируются с помощью плагина jquery-ui sortable. Вот хтмл код

```
    <div class="articlePreviewBox">

    <div id="block-teaserBox-teaserboxes" class="clear-block block block-teaserBox">

        <div class="content">

 <div class="boxes small future" id="engineering">
                <div class="boxes-head clearfix">
                    <h2 class="sifr-head-link_"><a href="#">Engineering</h2><a class="handle"></a><a href="#">View All</a>
                </div>
</div>
<div class="boxes small future" id="events">
                <div class="boxes-head clearfix">
                    <h2 class="sifr-head-link_"><a href="#">Events</h2><a class="handle"></a><a href="#">View All</a>
                </div>
</div>
<div class="boxes small future" id="future">
                <div class="boxes-head clearfix">
                    <h2 class="sifr-head-link_"><a href="#">Future</h2><a class="handle"></a><a href="#">View All</a>
                </div>   
</div>
<div class="boxes small future" id="heritage">
                <div class="boxes-head clearfix">
                    <h2 class="sifr-head-link_"><a href="#">Heritage</h2><a class="handle"></a><a href="#">View All</a>
                </div>    
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот код для куков (подключен плагин для куков)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.articlePreviewBox').sortable({
        handle:'.handle',
        helper: "clone",
        containment: '.articlePreviewBox',
        revert:true,
        scroll:true,
        scrollSensitivity: 100,
        scrollSpeed:10,
        cursor:'move',
        tolerance:'pointer',
        items:'.small',
        start: function(e, ui) {
        ui.placeholder.html(ui.item.html());
        ui.placeholder.css({
            'visibility': 'visible',
            'opacity': 0.3
        });
    }
});

//SAVE LEFT-COLUMN ORDER TO COOKIE
        var setSelector = ('.articlePreviewBox');
        var setCookieName = "listOrder1";
        var setCookieExpiry = 7;

        function getOrder() {
            jQuery.cookie(setCookieName, jQuery(setSelector).sortable("toArray"), { expires: setCookieExpiry, path: "/" });
        }

        function restoreOrder() {
            var list = jQuery(setSelector);
            if (list == null) return

            var cookie = jQuery.cookie(setCookieName);
            if (!cookie) return;

            var IDs = cookie.split(",");

            var items = list.sortable("toArray");

            var rebuild = new Array();
            for ( var v=0, len=items.length; v<len; v++ ){
                rebuild[items[v]] = items[v];
            }

            for (var i = 0, n = IDs.length; i < n; i++) {
                var itemID = IDs[i];
                if (itemID in rebuild) {
                    var item = rebuild[itemID];
                    var child = jQuery(setSelector+" .block-teaserBox .content").children("#" + item);
                    var savedOrd = jQuery(setSelector+" .block-teaserBox .content").children("#" + itemID);
                    child.remove();
                    jQuery(setSelector+" .block-teaserBox .content").filter(":first").append(savedOrd);
                }
            }
        }

            jQuery('.articlePreviewBox').sortable({
                update: function() { getOrder(); }
            });
            restoreOrder();
});
```

Сам код как-то странно работает, то сохраняет позицию, то не сохраняет, никак не могу разобраться с ним, надеюсь на Вашу помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ложная тревога: у одного блока движок генерировал не правильный id = "modern cars", из-за этого пробела и была ошибка, а так все работает.